# Java heap space on an array of 1134890 x 1134890

Tags: java, exception, memory

I am trying to manage a big set of data which means I need to create an Array like this:

```
double[][] myArray = new double[1134890][1134890];
```

By doing so, I get an exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

I tried to run it with the following parameters to increase the memory of my virtual machine:

[image: Screenshot of my running configuration]

But I still get the same error...
First, did I get it right with the parameters? And if so, is there any chance I can make my program work?

Comment: 1134890 * 1134890 = 1287975312100, over 1.2 trillion.  At 8 bytes per `double`, you'd need 9.6 TB memory.  Any chance that this will be a sparse array?

Comment: @rgettman There is a tiny bit of overhead for the arrays too :)

Comment: Arrays can only have a max size of about 2.14 billion by default. Even with allocating 2G of memory, you're way over the limit for 2G with 1134890 x 1134890.

Comment: @LucasBaizer, Re "by default", isn't that a hard limit in Java?  Java has no analogue of `size_t` -- arrays are indexed by `int`s which are speced as 32b signed.  But on the other hand, multi-dimensional arrays in Java are always [jagged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array), so the whole volume need not fit in a single index.

Comment: On the plus side though, the parameters were spot on. But you should only pass them as **VM arguments** and not **Program arguments**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this is a very huge array have you considered the idea to use a [sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)?

Basically a sparse matrix is a data structure where you save only data that haven't a default value.

Here is a possible basic implementation of a sparse matrix.

```
public class SparseMatrix {
    private Map<String, Object> map;
    private Object default;

    public SparseMatrix(Object default) {
        this.default = default;
        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    public Object get(int x, int y) {
        String key = x + "." + y;
        String value = map.get(key);
        if (value == null) {
            return default;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public void set(int x, int y, Object value) {
        String key = x + "." + y;
        if (value.equals(default)) {
           map.remove(key);
        } else {
           map.put(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** this is not a real implementation class. Take it only as a skeleton to start your code. For example here it is not possible to assign null to the default value, generics are not used for the definition of SparseMatrix and the key should be not a concatenation of strings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try this way !